# angularjs formly basic form not working

Tags: angular-formly

I'm new in angularjs-formly and this is my first try and I could not get my form working , please just be patient with me this is my first question and may be other questions will come after this one.

Here is my code :

`my plunker :`https://plnkr.co/edit/sxr64SXYZQ8yjtnOU3a2?p=preview

Please tell me what's wrong with this piece of code ?

Thank you.

/koul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/T0AAG5mY80hDNzVLKoKp?p=preview

```
(function() {
// Code goes here
angular
.module('plunker', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap'])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('mainCtrl is Loaded');
  var vm = this;

  vm.fields = [{
      key: 'id',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Id',
        placeholder: 'Enter Id',
        required: true
      }
    }, {
      key: 'name',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Name',
        placeholder: 'Enter ur Name',
        required: true
      }
    }];
});
})();
```

You were missing the extra "}" after the templateOptions on the first one, and there were a few other things I did.  I usually wrap any js files in a closure, and its not good practice to use var with angular, you just type angular then .module or .controller.  If you are just learning angular, you should ditch the controllers and learn components, as that is the proper way now.

Also, the references to the libraries were not correct...some of those links don't work anymore. A quick look at the debugger, via F12 would have shown those as being problematic.